# Trying to print dictionary values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to write a simple program that asks for input of a favorite rainbow color first letter (ROYGBIV) and print the value of the letter given. For example, if user input is "R", the program will print "Red". I tried to use dictionaries but I couldn't get it to work. Could you help me correct my mistakes?

```
def rainbow():

    color = {
        "R", "Red"
        "O", "Orange"
        "Y", "Yellow"
        "G", "Green"
        "B", "Blue"
        "I", "Indigo"
        "V", "Violet"
        }

    userint = input("Enter first letter of fav color: ").upper()

    if userint in color:
        print color.get(userint,"none")

    else:
        print("no match")



rainbow()`
```

Comment: That is not valid dictionary syntax. The key is separated from the value by a `:`, and the key-value pairs are separated by `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have it, `color` is currently a Python [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) that looks like this:

```
{'BlueI', 'GreenB', 'IndigoV', 'OrangeY', 'R', 'RedO', 'Violet', 'YellowG'}
```

The syntax for constructing a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) needs colons, not commas, for key/value pairs:

> Dictionaries can be created by placing a comma-separated list of key: value pairs within braces, for example: `{'jack': 4098, 'sjoerd': 4127} or {4098: 'jack', 4127: 'sjoerd'}`, or by the `dict()` constructor.

In your case, this would be:

```
color = {
    "R": "Red",
    "O": "Orange",
    "Y": "Yellow",
    "G": "Green",
    "B": "Blue",
    "I": "Indigo",
    "V": "Violet"
    }
```

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
color = {c[0]: c for c in 
         {'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo', 'Violet'}}
```

Lastly, if you're curious as to why "Green" and "B" (among others) are smushed together, that is because of Python's [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).